# how to C++ move content from dynamically allocated array to new resized

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary, dynamic, tile

I'm trying to learn c++ and dynamic arrays are confusing.

So I'm using making a game's TileMap system with 1D array as 2D (x + width * y). Each cell holds an index used for tile drawing. But I want to make an option to resize the TileMap. Arguments are for border resizing.

So questions are:

Am I doing new array creation and deletion correct?

What is the correct logic to move over the data? I see that indexes are assigned wrong.

```cpp
void TileMap::ResizeMap(int left, int top, int right, int bottom){ //resize by cell
    int w = width -left +right;             //new width
    int h = height -top +bottom;            //new height

    int* tmp = tilemap;                     //preparing for deleting old pointer
    tilemap = new int[w * h];           //new TileMap grid populated with -1(empty) indexes
    std::fill(tilemap, tilemap+w*h, -1);

    //move old map to new map grid
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++){
        if (y-top >= 0 && y-top < h){

            for (int x = 0; x< width; x++){
                    std::cout << x << ' ' << y << ' ' << tmp[width*y + x ] << std::endl;
                if (x-left >= 0 &&  x-left < w){

                    tilemap[w*(y-top) + x-left] = tmp[width*y + x ];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    delete [] tmp;                          //remove old array
    tmp = NULL;

    width = w;                              //Save new width
    height = h;                             //save new height
}
//including Construct and deconstruct
TileMap::TileMap(TileSet& newTileSet, Vector2 mapPosition, int Columns, int Rows){
    tileset = &newTileSet;
    cell_size = tileset->tile_size;
    position = mapPosition;
    width = Columns;
    height = Rows;
    tilemap = new int[width * height];
    std::fill(tilemap, tilemap+width*height, -1);((float)height*cell_size.y));
}

TileMap::~TileMap(){
    delete [] tilemap;
    delete tileset;
}
```

[image]

Comment: what is `tilemap`?

Comment: In games usually, they are used to keep indexes for tiles (like NES games 16x16pixel blocks of image).

Comment: and btw, `new int[w * h]{-1}` is making its first element to -1, not the whole elements

Comment: I think you need to know the old, (top,left), or are they assumed to be 0, i.e, the new dimensions are relative to the old (top,left) ?

Comment: The top right example image is in case of (-1, -1, +1, +1). Meaning old (0,0) is in (1,1) position.

Comment: @NeZvers use `std::fill(tilemap, tilemap+w*h, -1)` after allocating

Comment: Learn to use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @김선달 Thanks, you were right about first being only one initialized. And thanks for std::fill.

Comment: @eerorika I will, but now I want to understand how to work with arrays.

Comment: @NeZvers vectors make life easier, when you switch from arrays to vectors you'll be glad that you did

Comment: @NeZvers Start with the basics. Manual dynamic allocation is advanced technique, that you'll hardly ever need.

Comment: @eerorika Thanks, I've been poking with basics too long and not knowing about pointers and allocation is bumming me out. That's why I created this challenge for myself.

Answer (score -1):

Am I doing new array creation and deletion correct?

```
int* tmp = tilemap;                     
tilemap = new int[w * h]{-1};
delete [] tmp;
```

**No**, since you deleting something else, we don't know what `tilemap` is, but assuming it is a static i.e. global `int*`, this would leak the last allocated map, plus it will cause undefined behavior in the first execution of this function, since you likely deference a null pointer.

Just use a `std::vector`.

Comment: tilemap is a class member that is initialized on constructor, now with some fix:

```cpp
    tilemap = new int[width * height];
    std::fill(tilemap, tilemap+width*height, -1);
```

In the referenced function I copied reference to tmp;

Created new array

```cpp
    int* tmp = tilemap;
    tilemap = new int[w * h];
    std::fill(tilemap, tilemap+w*h, -1);
```

Do the contend copy over to new array;

And then dereference a temporary pointer.

I WILL learn vectors when I'll understand this. I'm not going to leave the opportunity to learn.

Comment: To bad you did not post the complete code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If that helps I included construct and deconstruct.